# How to overwrite text by yank in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, paste, overwrite, yank

I want to overwrite text by yank as following. Is there any way to do this?

kill-ring:

```
text-i-want-to-paste
```

Before:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
^
corsor
```

After:

```
text-i-want-to-pasteuvwxyz
```

Answer (score 8):

Turn on `delete-selection-mode`. Then select the text to replace.  Then hit `C-y`.  With `delete-selection-mode` enabled, you just *type to replace* selected text, as is usual outside Emacs.  And `C-y` also replaces it.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use defadvice. Then this will only work when overwrite-mode is on:

```
(defadvice yank (before yank-if-overwrite)
  (if (bound-and-true-p overwrite-mode)
      (delete-char (length (current-kill 0))))
  )
(ad-activate 'yank)
```

Answer (score 5):

Here:

```
(defun crazy-yank ()
  (interactive)
  (delete-char (length (current-kill 0)))
  (yank))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-y") 'crazy-yank)
```